# Need to resend key if not processed?

Tags: loops, autohotkey

I have my first AHK script running, intercepting function keys and converting them to media keys (only if ScrollLock is enabled).  That works great.

However, if ScrollLock is not enabled, then I want AHK to just pass the key through to the running app.  So I added an else clause to just resend the key (see below) but that causes 70+ keystrokes per second once I hit F3.  As if I'm in a loop.

What is wrong with this code?

```
F3::
  if GetKeyState("Scrolllock", "T") {
    Send {Volume_Up}
    SoundBeep 1000, 50
    SoundBeep 1100, 50
  } else {
    SendInput, {F3}
  }
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$F3::
  if GetKeyState("Scrolllock", "T") {
    Send {Volume_Up}
    SoundBeep 1000, 50
    SoundBeep 1100, 50
  } else {
    SendInput, {F3}
  }
return
```

The problem that you had was that your `Send` command was retriggering the hotkey it was a part of, which can be prevented by using the $ modifier.

From the [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm):

> **This is usually only necessary if the script uses the Send command to
> send the keys that comprise the hotkey itself, which might otherwise
> cause it to trigger itself**. The $ prefix forces the keyboard hook to
> be used to implement this hotkey, which as a side-effect prevents the
> Send command from triggering it. The $ prefix is equivalent to having
> specified #UseHook somewhere above the definition of this hotkey.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a more complex script, with which the [caveats of `#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm#General_Remarks) could mess with, I'd recommend the following approach for any remap like this.

```
#If, GetKeyState("ScrollLock", "T")
F3::
    SendInput, {Volume_Up}
    SoundBeep, 1000, 50
    SoundBeep, 1100, 50
return
#If
```

This way F3 keeps it's original functionality when scroll lock is not on.

<sup>(Sending F3 isn't same as the key being actually used, some programs might not recognize a simulated keystroke, especially if it utilizes direct input, and you also lose the functionality of holding down F3)</sup>